# get work while loop in python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, while-loop

this script works in python2 but not in python3, the input question continues to be shown even if I put the correct answer :

```
correct = "no"
while correct == "no":
    answer = input("15 x 17? ")
    if answer == 15*17:
        correct = "yes"
        print 'good!' #for python2
    else:
        correct = "no"
```

how this can be solved both not using and using a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 `input` returns a string (in Python 2 `input` evaluates the input) so `answer == 15*17` will never be true unless you convert `answer` to an int or `12*17` to string.

Also, `print "good"` is not a valid Python 3 syntax as `print` is a function: `print("good")`.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in both Py2.7 and Py3 there are couple of differences between the language versions - see [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html):

- `input()` in py3 is equivalent to `raw_input()` in py2
- `print` is no longer a statement in py3 but a function

To make this code work across both py2.7 and py3 you can do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

while True:
    answer = int(input("15 x 17? "))
    if answer == 15*17:
        print('good!')
        break
```